# update state with flask sqlalchemy with postgres will not commit to database

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have read quite a bit of documentation and I can't see what is wrong with these lines

```
update_this = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
update_this.emailconfirmed = True
db.session.commit()
```

...and yet when I deploy the boolean column 'emailconfirmed' never is update to True. I have confirmed with print statements that `update_this.emailconfirmed` is False at the exact point in the code shown above... I just can't seem to update that value. Does anybody know what tests I can do, what imports I should check etc. etc.

Right now this is the top of my main .py file where the above code appears

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for, make_response
# the following line imports from models.py
from models import db, User
# the following line imports SignupForm from forms.py
from forms import SignupForm, LoginForm
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer

# Production (causes Heroku to redirect to SSL)
from flask_sslify import SSLify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


import os
app = Flask(__name__)
sslify = SSLify(app)
sslify = SSLify(app, subdomains=True)
app.config.from_pyfile('config_file.cfg')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
mail = Mail(app)
ts = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], salt=app.config['SALT'])
```

and this is my models.py file

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash


db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    role = db.Column(db.String(20))
    roleapproved = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    school = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    emailconfirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    pwdhash = db.Column(db.String(100))


    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, role, school, email, password):
        self.firstname = firstname.title()
        self.lastname = lastname.title()
        self.role = role.lower()
        if role.lower() == 'student':
            self.roleapproved = True
        if role.lower() == 'teacher':
            self.roleapproved = False
        self.school = school.title()
        self.email = email.lower()
        self.set_password(password)
        self.emailconfirmed = False

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.pwdhash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.pwdhash, password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {0}>'.format(self.email)
```

Any help on doing the update I mentioned above would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The proper fix is to not have 2 separate instances of `db`. Your models should import the one defined in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ideally you want to maintain a single session throughout your application lifecycle. This way it makes it easy to reason about and you avoid binding sessions to individual models.

Thanks @Ilja Everila

In `main.py` instead of initializing `SQLAlchemy`
you should write,

```
db.init_app(app)
```

<s>Define a `save` instance method for your User model.</s>

```
def save(self):
    """Saves model object instance
    """
    db.session.add(self)
    db.session.commit()
```

You can call this method to save the instance as

```
update_this.save()
```

*Another way to update the entity is to get the specific object session before committing*

```
from sqlachemy.orm import session
...
session = session.object_session(update_this)
session.commit()
```

Comment: When I do that I get an error `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<User at 0x7efd1d881710>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '2')`

Comment: There are two sessions in your code. One in your `models.py` and another where you made the query. You will need to get _session 1_ and commit that explicitly or define an instance method that uses session declared in `models.py`. I have updated my answer to do the later.

Comment: Or they should fix their app and not have 2 separate instances of `db` to begin with. Instance methods such as the `save()` tie session handling to the model objects, when they could and should be separate. Good for very simple "save this one object only", not so for larger atomic operations, and hiding commit to such might produce a few surprises in the long run.

Comment: I agree with you that it makes sense to have a single instance to db. Using `db.init_app(app)` is the right direction to go here

Comment: @Ilja Here's what I believe you are saying, would you please confirm? My main file is `app.py` and my `User` class is in `models.py`. So I think you are suggesting to have the line `db = SQLAlchemy()` in `models.py` before I define the `User` class. And then in `app.py` (main) you are saying I should have `from models import db` and `app = Flask(__name__)` and `db.init_app(app)`. (With, of course, the necessary `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']` content shown in my original post). This works. But if it's not what you had in mind would you please give a more comprehensive post? Thanks!!!

Comment: On the road, so a lot afk, but that'd seem ok, I guess. I'm not super familiar with Flask, but I do know `db` is meant to be a singleton.