# Update Row using SQLAlchemy Flask and sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update the user password using SQLAlchemy and flask but the changes are not being commited

```
change_admin_password = Blueprint('change_admin_password', __name__)
@change_admin_password.route('/api/users/password', methods = ['POST'])
@auth.login_required
def show():
    username = request.json.get('username')
    new_password = request.json.get('new_password')

    if username is None or new_password is None:
        abort(400)
    if username != app.config['ADMIN_USER']:
        abort(400)
    admin = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    admin.hash_password(new_password)
    db.session.commit()
    return (jsonify({'success': True, 'message': 'Admin password changed'}), 201)
```

And in the User class I have

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(64))
    roles = db.Column(db.String(128))
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())

    def hash_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = pwd_context.encrypt(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return pwd_context.verify(password, self.password_hash)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

Update:
If I try to add a new user before the commit, the new user is added to the table but the admin still has the old password

```
admin = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
admin.hash_password(new_password)
user = User(username='admintest')
user.hash_password(new_password)
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Maybe you need to flush after commit if autoflush isnt on

Comment: @bboumend [Commit always flushes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.commit). To OP, how are you verifying that the changes are not committed?

Comment: @IljaEverilä If I try to login using the new password it does not but the old password works. Also if I query the users tables from the terminal I can see that the password still has the same old hash

Comment: Do you happen to have 2 instances of `db`, one you use to create the models, and the other you're using in the views etc.?

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes actually in my run.py I import db from the sqlalchemy declaration model and I also import it in the above code where the user is updated. Also I tried moving the code to run.py the commit worked fine. I guess it has something to do with circular db reference I am new to python and reading about it now.

Comment: But do you import `db` consistently from 1 place? In other words you don't have 2 `db` objects, for example `app.db` and `models.db` or some such? What I'm trying to get at is that maybe your models are using a separate session, and so though you commit, you don't commit the changes held in that other session. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608370/update-state-with-flask-sqlalchemy-with-postgres-will-not-commit-to-database) for a possibly similar case.

Comment: Thank you @IljaEverilä that was the problem! i removed the initialization from the run.py and just did `db.init_app(app)` it worked fine. But why was the user being saved then? is creating a row session independent ?

Comment: You had 2 separate versions of `db` apparently. Adding a new object to the `db.session` you were using and committing works for obvious reasons, but the reason why the queried objects did not persist changes was that the models were using a *different* scoped session.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after I removed the initialization of the db from run.py and imported db from a single place in all my models.

So in sqlalchemy_declaration I have

`db = SQLAlchemy()`

and in other models

`from sqlalchemy_declarative import db`

Then I initialize the app with

`db.init_app(app)`